# Expressions for symmetric power sums in terms of lower symmetric power sums

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, recurrence-relations, algebraic-combinatorics

The Newton symmetric power sums $p_k(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, for $k \geq 1$, are given by
$$
p_k(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^k.
$$
Do you know if it's possible to express $p_k$ in terms of (non-linear combinations) of the $p_j$'s with $j < k$ (for characteristic $0$ fields)? Is there some sort of recurrence relation involving the $p_j$'s that avoids the elementary symmetric polynomials (a.k.a. Newton's identity)?

Note in here [Determinant expression for the power sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119841/determinant-expression-for-the-power-sum) that there is such an expression if we take $x_j = j$ for each $j$. I'm wondering if something of the sort holds in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A well-known identity in the ring of symmetric functions (see, e.g., Exercise 2.9.13(a) in [Darij Grinberg and Victor Reiner, *Hopf Algebras in Combinatorics*, arXiv:1409.8356v5](http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.8356v5)) says the following:

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. (Sorry, my $n$ is not your $n$. My symmetric functions are in infinitely many indeterminates.) Define a matrix
$A_n = \left(a_{i,j}\right)_{i,j = 1, 2, \ldots, n}$
by
$$
a_{i,j} =
\begin{cases}
p_{i-j+1}, & \text{if } i \geq j ; \\
i,         & \text{if } i = j - 1 ; \\
0,         & \text{if } i < j - 1
\end{cases}
\qquad \qquad \text{ for all } \left( i, j \right) \in \left\{ 1, 2, \ldots , n \right\}^2 .
$$
This matrix $A_n$ looks as follows:
$$
A_n
=
\left(
\begin{array}[c]{cccccc}
p_1   & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
p_2   & p_1   & 2 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
p_3   & p_2   & p_1 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
p_{n-1} & p_{n-2} & p_{n-3} & \cdots & p_1   & n-1\\
p_n & p_{n-1} & p_{n-2} & \cdots & p_2   & p_1 
\end{array}
\right) .
$$
Then, $\det\left(A_n\right) = n! e_n$.

Now, let us restrict these symmetric functions to $N$ variables $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_N$ for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$. (This $N$ is your $n$.) Then, for every $n > N$, we have $e_n = 0$, and thus $\det\left(A_n\right) = n! e_n = 0$. This is an equality involving $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n$, and $p_n$ only appears in it linearly with coefficient $\pm\left(n-1\right)!$, so you can solve it for $p_n$ (since your field has characteristic $0$). This expresses $p_n$ (for $n > N$) in terms of the $p_k$ with $k < n$. I don't know if this expression is as explicit as you want it to be, though...

You cannot do this for $n \leq N$ (with constant coefficients), of course, since $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_N$ are algebraically independent.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The power sum symmetric functions $p_k$ satisfy the linear recurrence

$$p_k - e_1 p_{k-1} + e_2 p_{k-2} \mp \dots + (-1)^n e_n p_{k-n} = 0$$

where the $e_i$ are the elementary symmetric functions. No hypotheses on the characteristic are necessary. This comes from the identity

$$\prod_{i=1}^n (t - x_i) = t^n - e_1 t^{n-1} + e_2 t^{n-2} \mp \cdots $$

after multiplying by $t^{k-n}$, then substituting $t = x_1, x_2, \dots , x_n$ and adding up the results.

Comment: I'm fully aware of the Newton identities you give. The question asks instead for a recurrence involving only power sums. That is, write $p_k$ in terms of other $p_j$ for $j < k$ (avoiding the $e_j's$). Thanks though.

Comment: @user152169: this is possible, but only starting with $p_{n+1}$, since $p_1, \dots p_n$ are algebraically independent. Use the above recurrence, and then replace the $e_i$ with more power sums: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Expressing_elementary_symmetric_polynomials_in_terms_of_power_sums

Comment: Thanks. In passing, in the case of characteristic $\ell >0$, would you know if it's always possible to express $e_k$, with $\ell \mid k$, in terms of the $p_k$ for $k \geq 1$ (possibly $k > n$). I've wondered about this for a while, but do not seem to find this anywhere online.

Comment: @user152169: In characteristic $2$, I can express neither $e_2$ nor $e_3$ through the power sums. (This is easy to check, since there are only two power sums to consider -- $p_1$ and $p_3$ -- as we have $p_2 = p_1^2$.)